# Form Mobile Validation - after other functions have run

Tags: validation, mobile

I need some help with the following issue. I am pretty new to JavaScript so this one is pretty tough for me. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

We have a form for registration that is already in use and I need to make some amends to it to enhance its usability. The form itself already contains several validation scripts and I need to add in a new one - an error message to appear next to the mobile field. I am unable to amend the form HTML itself so I have to do everything by javascript – I need to bind the new function to the submit button so that it fires AFTER all the other validations (field highlight, pop ups), but before the page turns over.

Here is the form (I have just left in the feild i need to amend) :

```
<form method="post" action="#" id="register_form" class="validate">
  <input type="hidden" name="page" value="" />
  <input type="hidden" name="unregistered" value="false" />
  <fieldset>
    <legend>I am a new online customer</legend>
    <div class="element">
      <label for="mobile_number">Mobile:**</label>
      <input name="mobileNumber" type="text" id="mobile_number" title="Please enter at least one number" class="text validate {validate:{minLength:10, eitherOr:'#telephone_number', messages:{minLength:'Please enter a valid phone number (at least @NUM digits long)', eitherOr:'Please enter either your Telephone or Mobile number'}}}" />
    </div>
    <div class="element continue_shopping_cont submit">
      <button type="submit" class="submit button small_button"><span>Register</span></button>
    </div>
    <input type="hidden" name="secure_from" value="" />
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Could someone help show me how i am supposed to do this and how is best to target this field?